# How to run loop parallelly to send email of report in python?

Tags: python

I have some data which I am processing to generate weekly reports of over 1000 individuals and sending them over smtp.

However, to do that I am running a loop which is a sequential process and takes about 3 min.

Is there any way to parallelize this process.

Current Process includes:

```
**import Library**
----------------------
**load data**
----------------------
**define data processing functions**
**define function to send mail**
----------------------
**In main function >
- groupby individual_id
- run loop for every group keys
  //Inside loop
    - get group
    - apply data processing function
    - send mail
----------------------
exit
```

Note:

**Every loop iteration gets the group applies data processing and send email to that particular individual and then moves to next iteration.**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should look into [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) for this. Multiple threads are great for when you have tasks which do not use a lot of computing power but are waiting for responses (in your case, sending the mails)